# Stuck in git loop

Tags: xcode, git, github

I had an issue where I accidentally copied a directory into a subdirectory of itself thus creating thousands of git transactions. After unsuccessfully trying to clean that up, I decided to create a new project and copy the files over from the old one. Somehow I think I've messed git up, but I'm not sure where the problem is. Here are my current symptoms.

I thought I initialized the git repository correctly. However, none of the files exist on github.

https://github.com/victorengel/matchismo2

... except what I created there.

The project itself is an iOS single view application that I created with git enabled. I copied over all the files I needed from the old project to the new project area, confirmed that it ran, and then tried a commit. The commit seemed to work, but the push didn't.

If I tried a push, I got a message that the working copy is out of date and that I should do a pull. If I tried a pull, it said there were uncommitted changes and I should abandon them or commit them. After some rooting around, I figured out that the change triggering this was a user data change that should have been ignored in .gitignore.

I finally have the .gitignore set up the way it needs to be. I think the repository is set up right on github.com, but I'm still getting errors.

I can commit but not push. If I try to push I get the message "Working copy out of date. Try pulling from the remote to get the latest changes, then push again."

If I try a pull, I get the message "matchismo2/master" is not a valid remote branch to pull from. Please choose a different remote branch.

Looking around at github.com, there is only one branch, master under victorengel/matchismo2. To me it looks like everything is set up properly, but apparently I'm missing something. What is it?

In Xcode, in the organizer, if I click on Branches, there is one item listed: master.
If I click on Remotes, there is one item, matchismo2, and if I expand it, master is listed.

I've been assuming this matchismo2 with master underneath it is what is supposed to match the "matchismo2/master" that's in the error message. Looks like a match to me, so why isn't it working?

EDIT:
If I try pulling from the GitHub application, I get an error message "There aren't any remote branches on the server yet." If I try publishing from GitHub, I get the following:

```
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
2013-03-05 16:32:43.680 GitHub for Mac Login[68518:707] AskPass with arguments: (
    "/Users/brillig/Downloads/GitHub.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub for Mac Login",
    "Password for 'https://victorengel@github.com': "
)
2013-03-05 16:32:43.763 GitHub for Mac Login[68518:707] Error reading attributes: OSStatus -2033889429
2013-03-05 16:32:43.764 GitHub for Mac Login[68518:707] Error reading attributes: OSStatus -2033889429
2013-03-05 16:32:43.919 GitHub for Mac Login[68518:707] Error reading attributes for password: OSStatus 840183217
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
To https://victorengel@github.com/victorengel/matchismo2.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://victorengel@github.com/victorengel/matchismo2.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
 (256)
```

Comment: Did you by chance accidentally copy the .git directory when you were copying files?

Comment: No. I copied the files I needed by category (images, model files, view files, controller files, storyboard files), so that is not possible.

Comment: are you aware that `.gitignore` only effects the defaults of `git status` and `git add`? Once files are tracked by git, git's knowledge of them supersedes any `.gitignore` rules. For example, it is not entirely uncommon to ignore *all* files, then `git add` only the files you actually want to track.

Comment: @WillPalmer, That makes sense, but I don't know how that relates to my issue.

Comment: @VictorEngel, So the reason why you are seeing warnings regarding uncommitted data, despite those files being in `.gitignore`, is that those files are already being tracked by git (and so are not effected by `.gitignore`). Not posting this as an answer, as it sounds like you have multiple problems, and I'm not sure what the root cause is.

Comment: The .gitignore issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

How about ensuring all your files are in order, renaming your branch, and pushing to the new (renamed branch) ? Then once you determine everything you need is actually there and your new code works, you can force update the master. Not an ideal way to do it, but it might work for you.

Comment: I don't have the same version of Xcode or even OSX anymore. The problem was resolved nearly a year ago, and I don't recall the details well enough to know whether your solution would work. I've since created many projects with a git repository with no problems, so I consider the question resolved, although I can't point to a specific solution. That's a long way of saying I can't accept your answer, but possibly only because the question is so old. Is there a way to close a question without selecting an answer (to prevent this from happening to others)?

Comment: ~renaming your branch~  seems to be the magic fix many times.